# How can I hide first the input fields and it's label first then it will show when I clicked the button

Tags: javascript, html

The tricky part on that input field is I can't hide the input field without adding !important how can I remove the display:inline-block?

My goal is to hide first the input fields then when I click the add another secondary license it will show. 
Take note that I can't edit the style code it defaults on the library I used

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD ANOTHER SECONDARY LICENSE</button></center>
<div class="wcfm-clearfix"></div>
</div>
<p class="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a wcfm_title"><strong>TYPE2</strong></p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a">TYPE2</label><input type="text" id="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a" name="wcfmvm_custom_infos[type2]" class="wcfm-text" value="" placeholder="" />
<p class="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e wcfm_title"><strong>NUMBER2</strong></p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e">NUMBER2</label><input type="text" id="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e" name="wcfmvm_custom_infos[number2]" class="wcfm-text" value="" placeholder=""
/>
<p class="d674f2caf5f73c6a51202e3f6186d03a wcfm_title wcfm_html_content_title"><strong>


<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a").style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<style>
#wcfm_membership_container input[type=text], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=file], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=password], #wcfm_membership_container select, #wcfm_membership_container input[type=number], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=time], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=search], #wcfm_membership_container textarea {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc!important;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #e9e9e9;
    line-height: 18px;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used `window.onload` event to hide those input fields in default and then if you click on the button they will be visible.

```html
<button onclick="myFunction()">ADD ANOTHER SECONDARY LICENSE</button></center>
<div class="wcfm-clearfix"></div>
</div>
<p class="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a wcfm_title"><strong>TYPE2</strong></p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a">TYPE2</label><input type="text" id="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a" name="wcfmvm_custom_infos[type2]" class="wcfm-text" value="" placeholder="" />
<p class="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e wcfm_title"><strong>NUMBER2</strong></p><label class="screen-reader-text" for="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e">NUMBER2</label><input type="text" id="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e" name="wcfmvm_custom_infos[number2]" class="wcfm-text" value="" placeholder=""
/>
<p class="d674f2caf5f73c6a51202e3f6186d03a wcfm_title wcfm_html_content_title"><strong>


<script>
  
  window.onload = () => {
      document.getElementById("b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(`label[for="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e"]`).style.display = "none";
      document.getElementById("a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a").style.display = "none";
document.querySelector(`label[for="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a"]`).style.display = "none";
  }
  
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e").style.display = "block";
 document.querySelector(`label[for="b9cb81bdafe237e5d269b1c3714d175e"]`).style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a").style.display = "block";
 document.querySelector(`label[for="a3a9af25dc3a4afd10d5b86f91fd115a"]`).style.display = "block";
}
</script>

<style>
#wcfm_membership_container input[type=text], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=file], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=password], #wcfm_membership_container select, #wcfm_membership_container input[type=number], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=time], #wcfm_membership_container input[type=search], #wcfm_membership_container textarea {
    background-color: #fff!important;
    border: 1px solid #ccc!important;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 8px 10px;
    width: 60%;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 15px;
    display: inline-block;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 5px 0 #e9e9e9;
    line-height: 18px;
}
</style>
```

Comment: may I know how about if I want to hide also the label?

Comment: Sure you can just hide those labels too. I've edited my code. Please check now.

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use this hidden attribute ?

```
elt.setAttribute('hidden', '');
elt.removeAttribute('hidden');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it:

```
element.setAttribute('style', 'display:inline !important');
// or
element.style.cssText = 'display:inline !important';
// or
element.style.setProperty("display", "inline", "important")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with CSS by wrapping the element you want to hide with `div` and give `display: none`. And on click change display to block

```
<div style="display:none" id="show">
[elements that you want to hide]
</div>

function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("show").style.display = "block";
}
```